# Ionic 4 ZBar crashing in ios

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ionic4, zbar

I'm using Ionic4 zbar to scan barcode. Every time I try to open the camera my application is crashing.I tried all different iphone devices.
My codes works fine on android devices.

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/zbar

Ionic:

Ionic CLI                     : 5.0.0 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.4.0
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.12.4
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 7.2.4
   @angular/cli                  : 7.2.4
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 1.4.0

Cordova:

Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
   Cordova Platforms : android 7.1.4, ios 5.0.1
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 3.1.2, (and 10 other plugins)

Utility:

cordova-res : 0.3.0
   native-run  : 0.2.2

System:

Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (/Users/conagrabrands/Library/Android/sdk)
   ios-deploy        : 1.9.4
   ios-sim           : 8.0.1
   NodeJS            : v10.16.0 (/usr/local/bin/node)
   npm               : 6.9.0
   OS                : macOS Mojave
   Xcode             : Xcode 10.2.1 Build version 10E1001

Expected result is camera should open to scan the barcode.

Answer (score 1):

I never got this ZBar plugin working on ios...
If you only want basic scanning features (barcode or qr-codes) I would advise to use the barcode scanner plugin

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/barcode-scanner

This is really stable and works fine on my app on both Android and iOS devices

Answer (score 0):

remove these lines from plugin

```
 UIView *infoButton = [[[[[self.scanReader.view.subviews objectAtIndex:2] subviews] objectAtIndex:0] subviews] objectAtIndex:infoButtonIndex];
        [infoButton setHidden:YES];
```